# How to show that $\text{gcd}(a,m)=d\land \text{gcd}(b,m) = 1 \implies (ab,m) = d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering whether my proof would be correct. Thank you in advance!

> From Bezout's we have that, $$bx+my=1,\text{ and}$$ $$ax'+my'=d.$$
>   Multiplying through by d we get, $$bdx+mdy=d.$$ Substituting we get, $$b(ax'+my')x+mdy=d$$ $$abx'x+bmy'x+mdy=d$$ $$ab(x'x)+m(by'x+dy)=d,$$ as desired.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that $ax+by=c$ has solutions if and only if $(a,b) \mid c$? If yes, then you can see why Bezout's theorem is true only in one direction, unless $(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Why is $ab(x'x) + m(by'x + dy) = d$ "as desired"?  That proves that $d$ is a multiple of $\gcd(ab,m)$ but not that $d$ *is* $\gcd(ab,m)$.  Bezuit's identity is not an if and only if statement.

Comment: @fleablood. See my comment to the A by egreg.

Comment: And see egregs response to your comment. The fact that the statement is true and can be shown to be true, does not mean an inference wasn't faulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bezout's theorem is not an "if and only if" statement unless $\mathrm{gcd}$ is $1$. However, we have the following theorem which is true and you can use it to solve your problem:

$\star$ **Theorem:** $ax+by=c$ has integer solutions if and only if $(a,b) \mid c$.

**Proof:** Suppose that $(a,b) \mid c$. Then by Bezout's theorem: $$\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}: ax_0 + by_0 = (a,b)$$
Since $(a,b) \mid c$, $\exists q\in \mathbb{Z}: q(a,b)=c$ which implies that $a(x_0q)+b(y_0q)=q(a,b)=c$.

For the other direction, suppose that $ax+by=c$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. We have $(a,b) \mid a$ and $(a,b) \mid b$. Therefore $(a,b) \mid ax+by=c$. $\fbox{ Q.E.D. }$

Back to your proof, your proof can be corrected like this:

$$(b,m)=1 \implies \exists x,y : bx+my=1$$
$$\exists x,y : ab(x)+m(ay)=a \implies (ab,m) \mid a$$

But $$(ab,m) \mid m$$

Therefore, $(ab,m) \mid (a,m)=d$. The other direction is equally easy and I leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

The “converse” of Bézout doesn't hold except for the case the greatest common divisor is $1$.

What you have proved is just that the greatest common divisor of $ab$ and $m$ is a divisor of $d$.

It’s easy to note, however, that $d$ divides both $ab$ and $m$, so you can conclude.

Comment: $( d|a \land d|m)\implies ( d|ab \land d|m) \implies \gcd(ab,m)\geq d$ and if $A(ab)+B(m)=d$ then $ \gcd(ab,m)|d$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, of course, but it should be stated in the proof.

Comment: Yes it should be.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet What does $A(ab) +B(m) = d$ mean?

Comment: @AlexD . If there exist integers $A, B$ with $Aab+Bm=d.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the  equation 
$$
bx_1+mx_2=d
$$
where $x_1=ax'x$ and $x_2=by'x+dy$, and use a contradiction argument.

Answer (score 0):

Bezout's identity is of the form:

$A\implies B$

Where $A$ is "$\gcd(a,b) = d$" and $B$ is "There are integers $x,y$ so that $xa + yb = d$.

However

$B \not \implies A$.

As a counter example:

Consider $6$ and $15$, then $x  = 4; y = -1$ then $6x + 15y = 6*4 - 15 = 9$.  But $\gcd(6,15) \ne 9$.

So  $ab(x'x)+m(by'x+dy)=d$ is not at all what was desired.

.....

Instead

Let $\gcd(ab,m) = e$ then there are $x,y$ so that $abx + ym = e$.  Then as $d|a$ and $d|m$ we must have $d|e$.

If we divide both sides of $abx +ym = e$ we have $\frac aebx + y\frac me = 1$.  And if we multiply both sides by $d$ we have $ ab\frac dex + m\frac dey = d$.  And as $e|ab$ and $e|m$ we must have $e|d$.

So we have $d|e$ and $e|d$ and as we are presuming these are positive integers. That must mean $d = e$.